# How do I determine the reason why a 3rd party sometimes does not get emails from me that I have sent?

Tags: email

I have a business office that I must correspond with by email.  I have been using a service named mailfence.  Recently the office did not get several emails I sent from mailfence.  I tried sending one from protonmail and that wasn't received either.  Then it did get some emails from me, to be followed by more lapses.  Their IT person said the problem wasn't on their end.  I had suggested looking at the log files to see if a buffer was full and emails were being rejected.  I then sent three duplicate emails from mailfence, protonmail, and gmail.  All of these were received.  Now, I sent another email from mailfence yesterday that wasn't received.  So, this looks like an intermittent problem.  What needs to be done to troubleshoot it, from both their end and my end?

Comment: Ask the recipient to look on their spam folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is little you can do here.   The ideal way to solve this problem is -

1. Send email.  Then get the information from your mail server about the send attempt.  Hopefully it will say the message was sent (ie accepted by the remote server).  If not, use the log message to work out why it was not forwarded on.

1a.  If you don't have control of the mail logs, escalate this to your provider, advising the details of the message and asking them for the logs.

2. Communicate with the sender or their mail provider advising the date, time, from, to and subject of the email, and confirming the log from your mail server confirming that their mail server accepted delivery.

The problem is unlikely to be a "full buffer" whatever that means.  If a mail server runs out of resources like disk or capacity it generally denies the email with an instruction to the sender to retry - which the sending mail server will do.    The problem is more likely to be related to spam classification or something to do with SPF or DKIM or reputation.

Another thing to do is to CC the message to another email account, and then have a look if that alternative account receives it - if so, look at the headers in the email and see if it gives you any clues about how the email was classified with respect of spam.